# How can I cite a question in SE?

Tags: support, faq, citation

Is there a way to cite a StackExchange question, in a way similar to arXiv.org for instance ?

For arXiv, I can just write **arXiv:1303.6666** for the article at link http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6666 and this is easier. I'm wondering if I can use something like **physics.SE:60738** for the question at link [Towing of asteroid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60738/) ?

EDIT: Of course, I do not want to cite a SE question inside SE, but outside, on a paper, in a presentation or during a lecture for instance. Sorry for the possible confusion.

RELATED QUESTION: [Do we want the citation tool from Math.SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/) Here we wonder if it exist a way to format citation without writing the full link, for instance to cite a question during a lecture or a presentation.

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/11305)

Comment: Manishearth opened [Do we want the citation tool from Math.SE?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4191/520) as well.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks a lot for this remark. But this is not exactly what I wanted to know. Most of the time, during presentation and/or lecture, I can not write a full link. Even if I did it, nobody will recopy it by hand. I wonder if it exists a shortcut that everybody would understand and easier to write, like for arXiv.

Answer (score 6):

Find the "cite" button underneath a post

[image]

Then click it, and you'll get the BiBTeX and amsrefs source for citing a post:

[image]

Comment: Yes sounds great this *cite* button. What I would like to know is if it exists some Stack-Exchange proposal like this one [http://de.arxiv.org/help/faq/references ] for arXiv.org. But I definitely vote for this *cite* button ;-)