# Do we want the citation tool from Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

> Related: [How can I cite a question in SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/how-can-i-cite-a-question-in-se)

[Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) has a citation tool. Basically, if you click "share" on a post, there's a little "cite" link:
[image]

Clicking that, you get:

[image]

This lets one properly cite a Physics.SE post in a document by the attribution rules.

Do we want this? While it may not be so useful for formal journal articles, I see how it could be useful for miscellaneous documents (remember, visitors can use it too).

Comment: Spiffy. I haven't seen a lot of what I would characterize as original work here, but there have been a few.

Comment: @dmckee: Don't we disallow original physics? Either way, there's a lot of great answers that would be nice to cite in lecture slides and tutorial/exercise sheets.

Comment: @dmckee Well, perhaps a way to encourage original contributions is by facilitating proper citations.

Comment: +1 to all the above comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been turned on for your site and is currently live. Cheers!

Comment: It's showing up; thanks! :D

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely. I've only been helped a few times now, but I would want to professionally acknowledge some of the most interesting answers and posters.

From a practical point of view, it is also very useful. Say, for example, one of my audience members wants to dwell deeper to an answer that I cite.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a great idea. There are lots of places besides a journal article where a proper citation is appropriate, and there are lots of reasons to cite good discussions even if they don't contain "original physics". For instance, I might cite a derivation given on SE in a set of review notes, or I might provide students with a reference to a post where the author did a really good job of asking for help with a homework problem. Attribution makes SE a better resource for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

absolutely! This will encourage people to present their sources which is very very important imo.